# p:commandButton layout conflicting with div

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces

I think this is a css question.

I have a fixed bar on the top of the page and I want to put there, aligned to the right, a p:commandButton. But the p:commandButton is rendered outside the div, to the left.

I've checked that it's probably a matter of attribute display, because the h:form (which must encapsulates the p:commandButton) has it defined as display:block. If I put the button outside the form, it's rendered like a charm where I want - but, of course, it doesn't work.. When i use the h:form, the button position is changed.

The css i'm using:

```
/*** Navigation bar ***/
body {
    padding: 0; /* Gets rid of the automatic padding */
    margin: 0; /*   on HTML documents */
    font-family: Lucida Grande, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#navigation {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 55px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    /* Adds shadow to the bottom of the bar */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    /* Adds the transparent background */
    background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.9);
    color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.9);
}

#navigation a {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation a:hover {
    color: grey;
}

#navigation img {
    padding-left: 250px;
}
```

Comment: In cases with a lot of code, you will attract more attention if you conjure up a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Tks for the tip, but it's just a scroll of height with a couple of css classes. I dont think that someone willing to help will get stuck :-)

Comment: Just as a fast-but-not-good-solution, I've added some properties to my div containing the p:commandButton:
 #logged {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 206px;
 }

It does put my button where I want, but it's not relative to window's size: if I resize it, everything goes overlapping